# Using mode for a range and ignoring blanks

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Almost got this working but can't quite get the last piece. I am trying to find the mode of a range of text cells, but crucially, ignoring the blank cells (the range is a series of drop downs with an initial value of a blank).

I have used this formula:

```
=iferror(INDEX(C5:K5,MODE(IF(C5:K5<>"",MATCH(C5:K5,C5:K5,0)))),"-")
```

It is almost there but only seems to become active when 2 or more cells are in play. I understand there would be an error if there are no common ones which I will fix with `IFERROR` but it seems that if I only have one result in my range, it ***doesn't*** register as a most common (until I select another cell too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FILTER()` to remove the unwanted blanks:

```
=IFERROR(IF(COUNTA(C5:K5)=1,filter(C5:K5,C5:K5<>""),INDEX(filter(C5:K5,C5:K5<>""),MODE(MATCH(filter(C5:K5,C5:K5<>""),filter(C5:K5,C5:K5<>""),0)))),"-")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but still the same issue. If only one cell in the range is 'active' a dash still appears. All seems fine when more than one comes into play.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12_d-3XfktWemkquuIuZ_IS6h-3aKq80C8hchu7ADWq0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks - seems to work perfectly! Out of interest, what was the issue from version 1? @Scott Craner

Comment: Actually, only prob I have noticed now is if there are 2 of the same for example, it sticks on the criteria that got there first - shouldn't it revert back to the dash as there's no more common than the other?